# reshape - how to restructure wide data by two columns

Tags: r

I am attempting to recast a data set that repeats across two variables (Date and States).

Here is a link to the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1nzv76kl6nvrnv/State%20Recast.csv?dl=0

The value inside each cell is Number of Clicks. The data is structured in such a way that after the Date and State Columns, the columns are Total Clicks, Desktop Clicks, Mobile Clicks, and Tablet Clicks arising via Paid, Organic, Direct, and Referral Web Traffic (so 16 columns).

I would like the data to be structured such that for each Date (Jan-12) and each State (Alabama, Alaska, etc.) there are 4 rows for Total, Desktop, Mobile, and Tablet, and within each category, a row for Paid, Organic, Direct, and Referral (so 16 rows for each Date and State)

Here is my crude attempt, but I'm not getting far given I am unsure how to specify two timevar values

```
l <- reshape(state, 
         varying = c("Paid.Clicks...Total","Paid.Clicks...Desktop", "Paid.Clicks...Mobile","Paid.Clicks...Tablet", "Organic.Clicks...Total" , "Organic.Clicks...Desktop" , "Organic.Clicks...Mobile"  ,  "Organic.Clicks...Tablet", "Direct.Traffic...Total"  ,   "Direct.Traffic...Desktop"  ,"Direct.Traffic...Mobile"  ,  "Direct.Traffic...Tablet","Referral.Traffic...Total"  , "Referral.Traffic...Desktop","Referral.Traffic...Mobile"  ,"Referral.Traffic...Tablet" ), 
         v.names = "Clicks",
         timevar = c("Date", "State"),
         times = c("Paid.Clicks...Total","Paid.Clicks...Desktop", "Paid.Clicks...Mobile","Paid.Clicks...Tablet", "Organic.Clicks...Total" , "Organic.Clicks...Desktop" , "Organic.Clicks...Mobile"  ,  "Organic.Clicks...Tablet", "Direct.Traffic...Total"  ,   "Direct.Traffic...Desktop"  ,"Direct.Traffic...Mobile"  ,  "Direct.Traffic...Tablet","Referral.Traffic...Total"  , "Referral.Traffic...Desktop","Referral.Traffic...Mobile"  ,"Referral.Traffic...Tablet"  ), 
         direction = "long")
```

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: 1. Link is broken.... 2. You can use melt() from "ddply" package if you are reducing 16 columns to 4, by reshaping it.

Comment: You mean like this? `data = read.csv("http://cl.ly/0m081s3g2L46/download/State%20Recast.csv", sep=",")
library(reshape2)
data_m = melt(data, .id=c(Date, State))`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
state$id <- with(state, interaction(Date, State))
v <- c("Paid.Clicks...Total","Paid.Clicks...Desktop", "Paid.Clicks...Mobile","Paid.Clicks...Tablet", "Organic.Clicks...Total" , "Organic.Clicks...Desktop" , "Organic.Clicks...Mobile"  ,  "Organic.Clicks...Tablet", "Direct.Traffic...Total"  ,   "Direct.Traffic...Desktop"  ,"Direct.Traffic...Mobile"  ,  "Direct.Traffic...Tablet","Referral.Traffic...Total"  , "Referral.Traffic...Desktop","Referral.Traffic...Mobile"  ,"Referral.Traffic...Tablet" )
l <- reshape(state, 
             varying = v,
             v.names = "Clicks",
             direction = "long")
l$time <- v[l$time]
```

Result:

```
> head(l, 10)
                                Date                State                          id                time Clicks
Jan-12.Alabama.1              Jan-12              Alabama              Jan-12.Alabama Paid.Clicks...Total    421
Jan-12.Alaska.1               Jan-12               Alaska               Jan-12.Alaska Paid.Clicks...Total     61
Jan-12.Arizona.1              Jan-12              Arizona              Jan-12.Arizona Paid.Clicks...Total    768
Jan-12.Arkansas.1             Jan-12             Arkansas             Jan-12.Arkansas Paid.Clicks...Total    205
Jan-12.California.1           Jan-12           California           Jan-12.California Paid.Clicks...Total   2471
Jan-12.Colorado.1             Jan-12             Colorado             Jan-12.Colorado Paid.Clicks...Total    463
Jan-12.Connecticut.1          Jan-12          Connecticut          Jan-12.Connecticut Paid.Clicks...Total    647
Jan-12.Delaware.1             Jan-12             Delaware             Jan-12.Delaware Paid.Clicks...Total    114
Jan-12.District of Columbia.1 Jan-12 District of Columbia Jan-12.District of Columbia Paid.Clicks...Total    202
Jan-12.Florida.1              Jan-12              Florida              Jan-12.Florida Paid.Clicks...Total   3839
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what I wanted like this...

```
Total <- state[, c("Date", "State", "Paid.Clicks...Total", "Organic.Clicks...Total", "Direct.Traffic...Total", "Referral.Traffic...Total") ]
Desktop <- state[, c("Date", "State", "Paid.Clicks...Desktop", "Organic.Clicks...Desktop", "Direct.Traffic...Desktop", "Referral.Traffic...Desktop") ]
Mobile <- state[, c("Date", "State", "Paid.Clicks...Mobile", "Organic.Clicks...Mobile", "Direct.Traffic...Mobile", "Referral.Traffic...Mobile") ]
Tablet <- state[, c("Date", "State", "Paid.Clicks...Tablet", "Organic.Clicks...Tablet", "Direct.Traffic...Tablet", "Referral.Traffic...Tablet") ]

Total.r <- melt(Total, .id=c(State, Date), variable.name = "Medium", value.name= "Clicks")
colnames(Total.r) <- c("State", "Date", "Source", "Clicks")
Total.r$Source <- factor(Total.r$Source, labels = c("Paid", "Organic", "Direct", "Referral" ) )
Total.r$Medium <- c("Total")

Desktop.r <- melt(Desktop, .id=c(State, Date), variable.name = "Medium", value.name= "Clicks")
colnames(Desktop.r) <- c("State", "Date", "Source", "Clicks")
Desktop.r$Source <- factor(Desktop.r$Source, labels = c("Paid", "Organic", "Direct", "Referral" ) )
Desktop.r$Medium <- c("Desktop")

Mobile.r <- melt(Mobile, .id=c(State, Date), variable.name = "Medium", value.name= "Clicks")
colnames(Mobile.r) <- c("State", "Date", "Source", "Clicks")
Mobile.r$Source <- factor(Mobile.r$Source, labels = c("Paid", "Organic", "Direct", "Referral" ) )
Mobile.r$Medium <- c("Mobile")


Tablet.r <- melt(Tablet, .id=c(State, Date), variable.name = "Medium", value.name= "Clicks")
colnames(Tablet.r) <- c("State", "Date", "Source", "Clicks")
Tablet.r$Source <- factor(Tablet.r$Source, labels = c("Paid", "Organic", "Direct", "Referral" ) )
Tablet.r$Medium <- c("Tablet")


recast <- rbind(Total.r, Desktop.r, Mobile.r, Tablet.r)
```

Not the most parsimonious solution, but for those that may wonder how I was structuring the data, here you go.